# Docker error The command non-zero code: 1 python

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

i have problem when i tried to build container. And the error is :

```
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

i don't know why, i follow the code from documentation but always get error.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7-slim
#
# # Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app
#
# # Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app
#
# # Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
#
# # Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80
#
# # Define environment variable
ENV NAME World
#
# # Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: Attach to the container manually and run the same command

Comment: I update the dockerfile in the question

Comment: And when you run the docker build, where is the requirements file?

Comment: In the same folder with Dockerfile and app.py

Comment: Okay, then I guess the solution is to `docker run --rm -ti python:2.7-slim sh` and see what the error is

Comment: I was check my requirements.txt, On the docker document just add python and Redis, i tried to improv and i was add scrapy in requirements.txt. After i delete scrapy, it's working. Can you explain that, why ?

Answer (score 2):

Seems issue with the location of the file try to give absolute path of the file that you are referring in dockerfile